# Issues with Sending Web Push Notifications

Tags: php, web-push

I am having some issues figuring out how to send the actual notification.  I have been through several step by step tutorials and am able to get those to work within the browser I am working on, however, none explain how to install the web push library for PHP or how to send the actual notification to a specific endpoint.  Does anyone have a tutorial explaining how to install the web push library for PHP or how to send the notification once the user is subscribed?

I have gone through Google's codelab for adding Push Notifications to a Web App and was able to get it to work, however, it doesn't explain how it works on the back end.

I also went through Mozilla's Web Push demos, however, still very vague when it comes to sending the notification to specific users.

Comment: Per https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php, installation is as simple as `composer require minishlink/web-push`, and they've provided code samples. What, **specifically** are you struggling with? We don't do "gimme a tutorial" questions here.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask questions about coding problems and we provide simple answers.  What you asked is not that and btw Web Push is different for IOS as well as Android and is a very complicated question.

Comment: I use Network Solutions as my host, I don't know how to use composer with it.  If this isn't the place for my question, where is the place?

Comment: I forgot to tag.  @ceejayoz

Comment: So, start with learning how to use composer with your host. As long as they provide SSH access, it's fairly trivial to install and use. If they don't provide SSH access, you should be getting a different host anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up push notifications without developing your own app using notify.pm. It takes around 2 lines of code, the API is here:
https://github.com/notifypm/notifypm-php-api

```
<?php

require_once("notifypm.class.php");

$n = new Notifypm('email', 'password', '.pmNumber');
$n->push('Message!', 'Link (optional)!');

$n->disconnect();
```